# SQL Count Rows From Multiple tables

Tags: mysql, count

Lets say i have 2 tables

Companies

```
company_id    
name
```

Users

```
id
company_id
name
```

each company has multiple users assign to it... which is referenced in the company_id field from each record in the users table

HOW can i get a record showing the `(company_id), (company_name) and (number or users)`

for eg:

```
id# 1234 | name# Microsoft | n of users# 2000
```

I dont know how to make this query, i know i have to use the function `COUNT()` but i dont know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all companies even if they don't have any users yet use `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT c.company_id, c.name company_name, COUNT(u.id) no_of_users
  FROM companies c LEFT JOIN users u
    ON c.company_id = u.company_id
 GROUP BY c.company_id, c.name
```

Sample output:

```
| COMPANY_ID | COMPANY_NAME | NO_OF_USERS |
|------------|--------------|-------------|
|          1 |     Company1 |           3 |
|          2 |     Company2 |           2 |
|          3 |     Company3 |           0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07952/3)** demo

Comment: this is actually EVEN BETTER :D

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT companies.company_id,companies.company_name,COUNT(users.id)
FROM companies, users
WHERE companies.id = users.company_id
group by companies.id
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be the query

```
select Companies.company_id,Companies.name,count(Users .id) from Companies,Users where Companies=company_id  and Users =company_id group by company_id
```